# PDFBox | getting error while executing this line `PDDocument.load(input)`

Tags: grails, pdfbox

I'm getting an error that while execute the line `PDDocument.load(input)`

Code example:

```
PDDocument pd

String pdfDir = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.pdf"
File input = new File("${pdfDir}")

pd = PDDocument.load(input)  // System can't execute this line

pdfUtil.writePDF(pd, addr, data)
```

Error:

```
Error |
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1519)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:360)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:186)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1230)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1197)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1168)
Error |
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument$load.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
```

Dependency: `compile 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:1.8.11'`

Comment: likely empty input. Btw you're using an outdated PDF version. And if you insist on using 1.8, then you should load `loadNonSeq()` instead of `load()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, thanks to response!  I think input is not empty! There is a file path in the input

Comment: Yeah but the file itself. The contents. It should start with %PDF. Use NOTEPAD++ to look into it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I just tried `loadNonSeq()` instead of  ` load()`   I have to pass two parameter if I use `loadNonSeq()` but I am passing a parameter that Input, I need one more parameter like `RandomAccess`

Comment: You can pass null. But you will still fail if the file is empty.

Comment: Yeh, I failed again, how can I understand if the file is empty? I checked (by debugging) file is not empty, there is a file path. Can you suggestion me any thing else. Thanks @TilmanHausherr

Comment: A file *path* is not the same as the *content* of the file. Open the file with a text editor. Or double click on it if you're sure it is safe. You can also try to output the size of the file with `new File("${pdfDir}").length()`. I bet it is 0, or a very small number (smaller than 100).

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, I checked `length()`, its 0.

Comment: So that confirms what I wrote: the file is empty.

Comment: Does pdfFile exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: the file is empty. This is usually the reason when getting an exception like this

```
IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
```

with `parseHeader` in the stack trace.